# Last value for interest should be zero While loop

Tags: loops, while-loop

I am working on a standard homework assignment, but I can not get the last little thing to work out right.

```
print("Enter the purchase price:")
purchasePrice = input()
purchasePrice = float(purchasePrice)
downPayment = purchasePrice * 0.10
monthlyPayment = (purchasePrice - downPayment) * 0.05
annualInterestPayment = purchasePrice * 0.12
month = 0
balance = purchasePrice - downPayment

print("the purchase price is", purchasePrice)
print("the down payment is", downPayment)
print("the monthly payment is", monthlyPayment)
print("the annual interest is", annualInterestPayment)

#print("012345678901234567890")
print("%0s%20s%20s%20s%11s%22s" %("Month","Starting Balance","Interest to Pay","Principal to Pay","Payment","Ending Balance"))
#first %#s marks how far in it will go.
#with the h in month being placed where the number in %#s indicates
while balance >= 0.0:
    month += 1
    currentBalance = balance
    currentInterest = (currentBalance * 0.12)/12
    currentPrincipal = monthlyPayment-currentInterest
    endingBalance = currentBalance - currentPrincipal
    print("%0d%20.2f%20.3f%20.2f%13.2f%23.2f" %(month, currentBalance, currentInterest, currentPrincipal, monthlyPayment, endingBalance))
    balance = endingBalance
```

it works for the most part, i do not know what to do to get the interest value at the end to be zero. All the solutions I have tried make it an infinite loop.